# Am I weird for wanting to buy this to record?

Tags: sound-effects

[LINK TO COOL TOY](http://cgi.ebay.com/TURBO-SPOKE-Make-Bicycle-Sound-Like-Motorbike-FREE-SHIP-/130406992342?cmd=ViewItem&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e5cdcc9d6#ht_739wt_1139).

Answer (score 2):

Ha!  When I was a boy we used to fasten a piece of cardboard on the fork of our pushbikes using an ordinary sprung clothes-peg, so that the cardboard was rattled by the spokes of the wheel as it turned.

Which made it sound *just* like a motorbike. :)

Wouldn't be suprised if this is similar but with fake exhaust that just happens to act as a passive amplifer...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're definitely not weird although it's nothing authentic. I'd rather spend my $20 on gas for the guy with an actual bike who's letting you record it! At worst you can make that device yourself and try varying the materials for the tube and the card :)

Answer (score 0):

Never! It seems awesome. And it's only 20 bucks. Please post the sound when you get it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! I want one too!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to spend 20 bucks either.  I'm experimenting with making my own...

Comment: Feel sorry for @Andrew :D